# How does unique pointer know the object is out of scope，and call the destructor automately？

Tags: c++

i dont know why the unique pointer implement is very very easy ，but unique pointer can destruct the object when this pointer out of scope.
There is anything else i dont know？

i write a test: I find when I call class's contruct fuction  like unique pointer, it will call T's destruct automately.
But when I call the function ,it will not call  T's destruct automately.
Now my question changes,i wonder why class's contruct fuction can do that ? It's RTTI? When MyPointer object destory itself?

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
class T{
    public:
    T(){
        std::cout<<"construct T"<<std::endl;
    };
    ~T(){
        std::cout<<"destruct T"<<std::endl;
    }
};
void fun(T *t){};
template<class T>
class MyPointer
{
private:
T *__contain;
public:
MyPointer(T *t):__contain(t){
}
~MyPointer(){
delete __contain;
};
};
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    {
    unique_ptr<T> a(new T) ;//call T' construct
    unique_ptr<T> *pa=new unique_ptr<T>(new T);// dont call  T' destruct
    MyPointer<T> mypointer(new T);//call T' construct
    
    T *t=new T;              //dont call  T' destruct
    fun(new T);              //dont call  T' destruct
    
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Same way all objects "know" they are out of scope, when they go out of scope.

Comment: 3Q but why unique pointer can destroy itself？The unique pointer implement is just like a normal class 
like others ，which can cause leak mem....

Comment: Not really. Unique pointers cannot be created by using the standard c++ and need compiler support to actually make it work.

Comment: @NiteyaShah That's nonsense.

Comment: @NiteyaShah Which part of `std::unique_ptr` implementation needs compiler support?

Comment: @NiteyaShah what do you mean with `cannot be created by using the standard c++`? Why shouldn’t that be possible?

Comment: this is what  i want to know。But How can to learn the actual unique pointer implement from the compiler or its mechanism

Comment: Do you know about destructors?

Comment: omg... Its harder  to me to understand it now..ヽ( ￣д￣;)ノ

Comment: Dang, Alan... very frustrating, and it happens a lot!  I've added my reopen vote.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Reopened, however long it lasts.

Comment: How do you think that c++ containers like `std::vector` can do that? Those also internally manage pointers and delete it when the container is destructed.

Comment: If you allocate a variable on the stack, the compiler will endure the destructor is called, when it goes out of scope. In `{ std::unique_ptr<int> foo = ...; }` the compiler inserts the destructor call at the closing bracket and this destructor call will do the cleanup, i.e. call `delete` on the raw pointer wrapped in `foo`...

Answer (score 0):

A `unique_ptr` is not much more than

```
template < typename T >
class unique_ptr
{
public:
  unique_ptr(T* p)
  :value(p)
  {}
  ~unique_ptr()
  {
     delete value;
  }
private:
  T* value;
};
```

There are a lot of other methods and constructors required for a complete implementation (especially the move constructor and assignment operator) but I've omitted them as they're not relevant to your question.

When you write:

```
void foo()
{
  unique_ptr<int> p(new int(5));
}
```

The new `int` pointer is stored in the `unique_ptr` object `p` and at the end of the `foo` function `p` is destructed which calls the `unique_ptr` destructor which deletes the pointed to `int`. Any locally allocated object will be destructed when it goes out of scope. A `unique_ptr` is no different it deletes the pointer it owns in its destructor. Note that if you allocate a `unique_ptr` with `new` it is the same as any other object it wont be destroyed until you call `delete`:

```
void foo()
{
  unique_ptr<int>* p = new unique_ptr<int>(new int(5));
}
```

It's safe to say that you should pretty much never be using a dynamically allocated `unique_ptr` as that would defeat the purpose of using `unique_ptr`.

To clarify this code:

```
void foo()
{
  unique_ptr<int> p(new int(5));
  unique_ptr<int>* q = new unique_ptr<int>(new int(5));
}
```

Will make the compiler generate something like this:

```
p = stack_allocate(sizeof(unique_ptr<int>));
temp = stack_allocate(sizeof(int*));
*temp = heap_allocate(sizeof(int));
**temp = 5;
p->construct(*temp);
stack_free(temp);
q = stack_allocate(sizeof(unique_ptr<int>*));
*q = heap_allocate(sizeof(unique_ptr<int>));
temp = stack_allocate(sizeof(int*));
*temp = heap_allocate(sizeof(int));
**temp = 5;
(*q)->construct(*temp);
stack_free(temp);
stack_free(q);
p->destruct();
stack_free(p);
```

(In reality some of the variables are probably just held in registers not on the stack but this is generally how the generated code looks). Notice that all the stack allocated variables are automatically destroyed and deallocated whereas those created by `new` on the heap aren't.

Comment: 3q! You inspire me

Comment: I edit my question,i wonder how class know that T object is out of scope,and delete it?

Comment: The class doesn't know, the compiler inserts a call to the destructor at the end of the objects scope

Comment: oops.it might be too difficult for me to figure out what you answer ,haha,i have just learned C++ for less one year,but thank you much~ Could you please recommend me some  books or else about C++ RTTI or what C++ compiler do behind.i want learn it deeper,but dont konw how

Comment: I think you might just be over thinking this, all objects are destroyed at the end of their scope unless you create them with `new`, in that case you need to call `delete` to destroy them